# Outputting front page to a different url

Tags: 7

I currently have this site [tobyNews](http://www.tobynews.com) that is up and running with Drupal 7. However, 
while in the process of giving the site a mobile version, I thought maybe it would be easier if the front page content that is displayed when you first visit the site was simply output to another page, like m.tobynews.com . Is there any way to sort of add another output without altering the main page?

Comment: you want a suggestion/solution only for front page not inner pages as well?

Comment: why don't you design a responsive website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally suggest putting breakpoints into the CSS and making the site adaptive. You would save yourself a lot of time building a separate mobile site.

Plus, especially with adaptive widths, and not fixed widths, you allow your site to display nicely on all sizes of device screen, and when a user reduces the size of their browser window on a desktop.

Alternatively, To detect a device and show a different site e.g. m.yoursite.com have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/2291761).